# Logstash & Elasticsearch mass log process

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to know what's the best configuration for processing mass log files - I've enabled AWS new feature, ELB logs and would like to ship all to an elasticsearch using logstash,

I have almost 400 Million requests per day, which architecture should I choose?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For Logstash/Elasticsearch it "all depends" on your events, how complex your Logstash configurations are, and how complex the resulting events are.
Best is to do a proof of concept starting one index with one shard on one machine and fire events at it until you find the limit.
Same procedure for processing events with Logstash.

Then you'll have a reference for the hardware necessary to process your volume of events.